# Simulate gyroscope in Unity using compass and accelerometer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, accelerometer, gyroscope

I have been trying to simulate the gyroscope behavior in unity by using accelerometer and compass. So far I have achieved some functionality but it still has a lag; a delay of response. It does not change the view as fast as the tilt of the mobile phone. Any help is appreciated and thank you in advance.

Note: Z axis rotation is still not added.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GyroSimulator : MonoBehaviour {

float zValue;
float zValueMinMax = 5.0f;
Vector3 accelometerSmoothValue;
//Smooth Accelerometer
public float AccelerometerUpdateInterval = 1.0f / 100.0f;
public float LowPassKernelWidthInSeconds = 0.001f;
public Vector3 lowPassValue = Vector3.zero;
void Start () {
    Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.LandscapeLeft;
    Input.compass.enabled = true;
}
//Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    //Set Z Min Max
    if (zValue < -zValueMinMax)
        zValue = -zValueMinMax;

    if (zValue > zValueMinMax)
        zValue = zValueMinMax;

    accelometerSmoothValue = LowPass();
    zValue += accelometerSmoothValue.z;

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(
        transform.rotation,
        Quaternion.Euler(
            -zValue*5.0f,
            Input.compass.magneticHeading, 
            0
            ),
        Time.deltaTime*5.0f
        );
}

Vector3 LowPass()
{
    Vector3 tilt = Input.acceleration;
    float LowPassFilterFactor = AccelerometerUpdateInterval / LowPassKernelWidthInSeconds;
    lowPassValue = Vector3.Lerp(lowPassValue, tilt, LowPassFilterFactor);
    return lowPassValue;
}
}
```

Comment: I notice that each cycle you LERP towards your Input.acceleration value, rather than setting it directly.  THEN, you also slerp the quaternion toward the final direction, rather than setting (or offseting) it directly.  Could these be the cause of your lag?

Comment: Thank you, So can you please explain how should I set it directly without LERP and SLERP. This was the only way that I can think of to achieve this.

Comment: transform.rotation =  Quaternion.Euler( -zValue *5.0f,Input.compass.magneticHeading,0);